# Rally api for iteration burndown data

Tags: rally

I want to get burndown data for a particular iteration. I want to use that data to create my own graph. I don't want to embed Rally's chart. I want to just get the data. I am unable to find any suitable API for it. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an object in the web services API called IterationCumulativeFlowData.  You should be able to use these to create your chart:

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/iterationcumulativeflowdata?query=(IterationObjectID = 12345)

where IterationObjectID is the object id of the iteration you're charting.

Each IterationCumulativeFlowData object returned from that result will contain relevant information for each schudulestate- counts, estimate totals, etc. for each day in the iteration.